# Drop down click is not working in selenium java webdriver?

Tags: java, testing, xpath, junit, selenium-webdriver

Could you please anyone tell me what is wrong in my code.

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='idCallType_100']"));
        List<WebElement> Options = dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("option"));       
        System.out.println(Options.size());       
        for(int i=0;i<Options.size();i++)
        {
            WebElement o = Options.get(i);
            System.out.println(Options.get(i).getText()+ " ---- " + Options.get(i).getAttribute("value"));
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='idInsertTaskButton']/a")).click();         **// I couldnt able to click on this line**
            Options.get(i).click();
            System.out.println("coming for email time");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='idInsertTask_100']/div/div[1]/input")).click();   

        }
```

I am trying to click on drop down. For the very first click its working fine. form the next time its not executing from this line
  Options.get(i).click();
I dint know what is going wrong here.

```
Thanks!
```

Comment: How does it not work? Does it error? With what? Tried a different browser? What browser? What version of Selenium?

Comment: I am using selenium 2.35, updated version of Firefox and chrome in both the browser and  its working for the first time, from second time it is not working. And also i am error saying that element is not clickable at the movement.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you want to select an item from dropdown menu? Try to use 'Select' instead of the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your WebElement into Select Object as shown below

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("identifier")));
```

Once this is done you can select the required value in 3 ways. Consider an HTML file like this

```
<html>
<body>
<select id = "designation">
<option value = "MD">MD</option>
<option value = "prog"> Programmer </option>
<option value = "CEO"> CEO </option>
</option>
</select>
<body>
</html>
```

Now to identify dropdown do

`Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("designation")));`

To select its option say 'Programmer' you can do

`dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Programmer ");`

or

`dropdown.selectByIndex(1);`

or

`dropdown.selectByValue("prog");`